# Fullcalendar dayClick only for Admin

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

is it possible to get the dayClick Event only for the Admin?

I get the admin Information like this

```
$_SESSION["admin"] = yes/no
```

Greetings

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine JS and PHP like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // Rest of your Fullcalendar code
    <?php if($_SESSION['admin'] == 'yes'): ?>
    dayClick: function() {
        alert('a day has been clicked!');
    },
    <?php endif; ?>
    // Eventually more Fullcalendar code, if you like
});
```

This way, the dayClick event is only created when the user is admin.

Comment: That was easy! Thank you!